# For $x$ in $R^2$, does $x'Ax \ge ||x||^3 \forall x: ||x|| \le 1$ imply $x'Ax \ge ||x||^2 \forall x: ||x|| \le 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

For $x$ in $R^2$, does $x'Ax \ge ||x||^3 \ \forall x: ||x|| \le 1$ imply $x'Ax \ge ||x||^2 \ \forall x: ||x|| \le 1$?

I am almost certain it is not the case, but I can't think of a specific counter example.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $x'$ the transpose of $x$, and $A$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: x' is the transpose of x. Not necessarily

Comment: oh somehow I thought about complex matrices, sorry.

Comment: You can use `\lVert` and `\rVert` to get proper norm bars :-) Compare $\lVert x\rVert$ (`\lVert x\rVert`) versus $||x||$ `||x||`.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez $\| x\|$ is another option, `\|x\|`, and seems easier to write down.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff, the spacing that comes out of that is not quite correct ($\TeX$ uses slightly different spacing rules for left delimiters and for right delimiters!) In an actual $\LaTeX$ file one should include the `mathtools.sty` package. say something like `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}` in the preamble, and thereafter say `\norm{x}`. This has the added cuteness that one can then also say `\norm*{something big}` and the bars will scale as needed.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ah. I knew it had to be bad $\TeX$ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something a bit special about the second inequality. Can you see what it is?

*Hint*: Try dividing by the right hand side. Do you care about all possible vectors x?

---

To phrase this as simply as possible, and stress it has nothing to do with the fact this is a cube, or that we're in 2D:

Note we want $x'Ax \ge \lVert x \rVert^2$ which is equivalent, since $x=0$ is trivial, to $\hat{x}'A\hat{x} \ge 1$ for all unit length $\hat{x}$. But the condition given, plugging in $\hat{x}$, gives us this trivially since $1^3=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Kevin is right, there is an easier way. Let $x=(x_1, x_2)=(t\cos\theta, t\sin\theta)=tu$ where $t\in[0,1]$ and $u\in S^1$ the unitary circle, then $x'Ax\geq\|x\|^3$ is equivalent to $u'Au\geq t$ for all $t\in(0,1]$ and $u\in S^1$. But this implies that $u'Au\geq 1$ for all $u\in S^1$ which is equivalent to $x'Ax\geq \|x\|^2$ for all $\|x\|\leq 1$. The missing case is when $x=0$ but in that case the implication is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It is true! Since we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ without loss of generality we can assume that A is of three types (Jordan normal form):
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}a & b\\-b& a\end{matrix}\right),
$$
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}\lambda & 1\\0& \lambda\end{matrix}\right)
$$
or
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}\lambda_1 & 0\\0& \lambda_2\end{matrix}\right)
$$
If $A$ is of the first type, then $x'Ax=a(x_1^2+x_2^2)$, so if $x'Ax\geq\|x\|^3$ for all $\|x\|\leq 1$ then this implies that $a\geq\|x\|$ for all $\|x\|\leq 1$ which implies that $a\geq 1$, which implies that $x'Ax\geq \|x\|^2$.

If $A$ is of the second type, then $x'Ax=\lambda(x_1^2+x_2^2)+x_1x_2$, so if $x'Ax\geq\|x\|^3$ for all $\|x\|\leq 1$ we have that $(x_1^2+x_2^2)\left(\lambda-(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}\right)+x_1x_2\geq 0$. Let $x_1=t\cos\theta$ and $x_2=t\sin\theta$, for some $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ and $t\in[0,1]$ and define $f(t,\theta)=t^2(\lambda-t+\sin\theta\cos\theta)=t^2\left(\lambda-t+\dfrac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta\right)$. It is easy to see that $f(t,\theta)=(x_1^2+x_2^2)\left(\lambda-(x_1^2+x_2^2)^{1/2}\right)+x_1x_2$, so if $x'Ax\geq\|x\|^3$ for all $\|x\|\leq 1$ we have that $f(t,\theta)\geq 0$ for all $t,\theta$. But $f(t,\theta)\geq 0$ for all $t,\theta$, implies that $\lambda-t+\dfrac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta\geq 0$ for all $t,\theta$ which implies that $\lambda-1-\dfrac{1}{2}\geq 0$, that is $\lambda\geq \dfrac{3}{2}$. But this last implies that $\lambda-1+\dfrac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta\geq 0$, which implies that $t^2\left(\lambda-1+\dfrac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta\right)\geq 0$.

Now, $x'Ax\geq\|x\|^2$ for all $\|x\|\leq 1$ can be written as: $(x_1^2+x_2^2)\left(\lambda-1\right)+x_1x_2\geq 0$, but if $x_1=t\cos\theta$ and $x_2=t\sin\theta$, then the left hand side can be written as $t^2\left(\lambda-1+\dfrac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta\right)$.

The diagonal case is done in a similar fashion. Combining these three results we obtain the result.

Comment: Hmm.. There must be an easier way. This was on an old exam for a second course in analysis which doesn't really assume too much of a knowledge of theoretical linear algebra.

Comment: You are right, I posted a second proof: 3 lines!